# SQLite to PostgreSQL data-only transfer (to maintain alembic functionality)

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, pyramid, alembic

There are a few questions and answers already on PostgreSQL import (as well as the specific SQLite->PostgreSQL situation). This question is about a specific corner-case.

**Background**

I have an existing, in-production web-app written in python (pyramid) and using alembic for easy schema migration. Due to the database creaking with unexpectedly high write-load (probably due to the convoluted nature of my own code), I've decided to migrate to PostgreSQL.

**Data migration**

There are a few recommendations on data migration. The simplest one involved using

```
sqlite3 my.db .dump > sqlitedumpfile.sql
```

and then importing it with

```
psql -d newpostgresdb < sqlitedumpfile.sql
```

This required a bit of editing of sqlitedumpfile. In particular, removing some incompatible operations, changing values (sqlite represents booleans as 0/1) etc. It ended up being too complicated to do programmatically for my data, and too much work to handle manually (some tables had 20k rows or so).

A good tool for data migration which I eventually settled on was [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/), which 'worked' immediately. However, as is typical for data migration of this sort, this exposed various data inconsistencies in my database which I had to solve at source before doing the migration (in particular, removing foreign keys to non-unique columns which seemed a good idea at the time for convenient joins and removing orphan rows which relied on rows in other tables which had been deleted). After these were solved, I could just do

```
pgloader my.db postgresql:///newpostgresdb
```

And get all my data appropriately.

**The problem?**

pgloader worked really well for data but not so well for the table structure itself. This resulted in three problems:-

1. I had to create a new alembic revision with a ton of changes (mostly datatype related, but also some related to problem 2).
2. Constraint/index names were unreliable (unique numeric names generated). There's actually [an option](https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader/commit/7d2d09ce6896fa723da6d0581cb637208b2b5a96) to disable this, and this was a problem because I needed a reliable upgrade path which was replicable in production without me having to manually tweak the alembic code.
3. Sequences/autoincrement just failed for most primary keys. This broke my webapp as I was not able to add new rows for some (not all) databases.

In contrast, re-creating a blank database using alembic to maintain the schema works well without changing any of my webapps code. However pgloader defaults to over-riding existing tables, so this would leave me nowhere as the data is what really needs migrating.

How do I get proper data migration using a schema I've already defined (and which works)?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `pgloader my.db postgresql:///newpostgresdb?tablename=matching` option once your schema is already defined. This *might* need to be done on a table by table basis (I am not sure since I haven't used that option other than for importing CSV files)

Comment: That sounds possible, let me test and check that out. However I think based on what I've seen of pgloader so far that it will still drop the table and recreate it.

Comment: Having tested it it doesn't seem to work. The documentation seems to indicate that this is csv specific unfortunately

Comment: `:-(` pity. That was my use-case.

Comment: I think you can still use pgloader with a configuration file `WITH create no tables`. Check the *LOAD SQLite DATABASE* section of [pgloader(1) -- PostgreSQL data loader](http://pgloader.io/howto/pgloader.1.html). I've never used configuration files myself... so, this might as well fail, even if it looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

What eventually worked was, in summary:-

1. Create the appropriate database structure in postgresql://newpostgresdb (I just used `alembic upgrade head` for this)
2. Use pgloader to move data over from sqlite to a different database in postgresql. As mentioned in the question, some data inconsistencies need to be solved before this step, but that's not relevant to this question itself.

   `createdb tempdb`

   `pgloader my.db postgresql:///tempdb`
3. Dump the data in `tempdb` using `pg_dump`

`pg_dump -a -d tempdb > dumped_postgres_database`

4. Edit the resulting dump to accomplish the following:-

   - `SET session_replication_role = replica` because some of my rows are circular in reference to other rows in the same table
   - Delete the `alembic_version` table, as we're restarting a new branch for alembic.
   - Regenerate any sequences, with the equivalent of `SELECT pg_catalog.setval('"table_colname_seq"', (select max(colname) from table));`
5. Finally, `psql` can be used to load the data to your actual database

`psql -d newpostgresdb < dumped_postgres_database`